# How to extract value from the html provided through Selenium Webdriver and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

Have been playing around with Selenium Webdriver and i would like to extract certain information from a webpage. Below is the source code for webdriver

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DRIVER_BIN = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
driver = webdriver.Chrome ("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = DRIVER_BIN)
browser.get('https://www.abuseipdb.com/check/95.47.155.87')
```

I would like to extract the value 91% from this particular website and save it into a variable. Will need a solutions that are able to extract the % value out even if it's not 91%. Below are the html code.

```
<p>This IP was reported <b>222</b> times. Confidence of Abuse is <b>91%</b>: <a href="/faq.html#confidence" style="float: right; font-weight: bold;" class=text-muted>?</a></p>
```

Comment: Show what you've tried

Comment: Locate by CSS or XPath and retrieve it using `find_elements_by_css_selector` or `find_elements_by_xpath`.

Answer (score 0):

This will pull the first text of an *element* with a `<b>` tag containing `%` using **Xpath**:

```
abusePercentage = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//b[contains(text(), "%")]').text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xpath selector mentioned by `@PixelEinstein` or use the following css selector to get the text value

```
text_of_element = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('div.well > p:nth-child(2) >b:nth-child(2)').text
print(text_of_element)
```

This prints the value `91%` of the `<p>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

To extract the texts e.g. **91%** you can use the following solution:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='well']/h3//following::p[1]//following::b[2]").get_attribute("innerHTML")
```